# First-Order Logic and Set theory

Tags: reference-request, first-order-logic

I have learnt that first First-Order Logic (FOL) provides a formal language for set theory.
That given, one would expect that, when defining the symbols and rules of FOL, textbooks authors would do so without sets. However, textbooks I met use sets to explain FOL. This being the case, it make less sense to use FOL for set theory, because I already need the primitive notion of set to speak about FOL.

Initially, I thought that using the set-free approach was technically unfeasible. That's until I found a free ebook, doing so: [An Introduction to Set Theory by Professor William A. R. Weiss](http://www.math.toronto.edu/~weiss/Set_Theory.pdf).

- Is there a particular reason for following the other approach (FOL based on set, then introduction to axiomatic set theory)?
- I would also read more in the Weiss style. Can you give me some references about books not using sets when explaining the formal language? I tend to prefer textbooks as references (rather than seminal papers/books).

Comment: The link you provided doesn't use a "set-free" approach. Weiss begins his description of the language by "a complete list of the symbols of the language" : what's a symbol, what's a list ? He then talks about strings, formulas, what are they ? They're sets, that's all. The thing is, you need a sort of "naive set theory" to begin with, to describe first order logic and within FOL you can define formal set theory, which is nothing more than a first order theory. What one then argues is that the "naive mathematical world" can be represented inside this first order theory

Comment: @Max - "...what are they ? They're sets, that's all." This is a pretty silly statement. We don't need naive set theory (unless using the word "collection" at all is the only qualification, which is a bit of a ridiculous one) to talk about the Latin alphabet and English words. The case for first order language is no different. We know what symbols and words and sequences are independently of knowing how they might be modeled by sets. The reason to worry about these implementations is only when we mathematically want to study first order logic itself, not just use it as a metalinguistic tool.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine: The Latin alphabet and English words aren't usually accepted as mathematical objects. The fact that sets can be used as a primitive notion that doesn't need a definition (for all intents and purposes of naive set theory) is accepted by many (unless I'm wrong), whereas I doubt you'd find many mathematicians happy with the thought of having the english language (or any other "natural language") as a primitive notion. The fact that these can be modelled by sets is satisfactory in a sense, whereas saying "Oh I don't know what 'collection' means, but it's definitely not a set"(cont)

Comment: (cont) doesn't seem as satisfactory to me (although here we enter the realm of opinion and philosophy)

Comment: @Max - We're not comparing the English language and sets as primitive notions; we're comparing the English language and first order logic as mathematical objects or metalinguistic tools. And the point is, using first order logic as the latter, we don't have to employ any special ontological categories to do so that we don't employ in talking about written natural language (which we can also model as mathematical entities, save that we can't specify well-formedness conditions so easily).

Comment: @MaliceVidrine I see your point. I may have been wrong then.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine: I am not up to the elegance of your speech. More pragmatically I'd say it is not a problem using expressions like "set of symbols", when introducing FOL. In this case the word "set" is part of the English metalanguage used to describe FOL and is not the "set" object part of the Set Theory. My question, instead, deals with approaches along the lines of "Let $L$ be a language, and let $U$ be a set. It is understood that $U$ is disjoint from the set of variables. The set of $L$-$U$-formulas is generated as follows...." (Simpson). This clearly presupposes a technical notion of set.

Answer (score 1):

There is a pretty good introduction to First Order Logic and it is an open source book provided by P.D. Magunus. As you say, Truth Funcional Logic and First Order Logic are defined without using Set Theory. I leave you here the link: https://www.fecundity.com/logic/download.html

Comment: Thanks, interesting book. Pity that the author does not use the FOL to build a set theory, that is to define class terms, membership predicates, etc.