# Define sequences without sets or natural numbers

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I wondered whether it  is possible to define a sequence without relying on sets or  natural numbers and tried with this definition.

1. A symbol which is not a comma is a sequence.
2. If $S$ is  sequence and $s$ a symbol which is not a comma:

   - $S, s$ is a sequence, where every symbol  occurring in $S$ precedes  $\phi$ and  $\phi$ is the last symbol  of the sequence.
   - $s, S$ is a sequence, where every symbol  occurring in $S$ follows $\phi$ and  $\phi$ is the first  symbol  of the sequence.

So given  the string "$a,b,c$",  "$a$" is a sequence and  "$a,b$" is a sequence too. Therefore "$a,b,c$" is the sequence "$S, c$", where "$S$" is "$a,b$", "$c$" is its last element and "$a,b$" precede it. Similarly "$a$" can be  identified as the first element.

Is that  correct?

Comment: It depends on the foundations.  For instance, Coq's type-based mathematical foundations directly define a (finite) list of elements of a type `A` in terms very much like this.  (Of course, if you consider a "type" to be too close to a "set", you might not like it as much - but then again, you hardly ever talk about generic sequences anyway, without specifying that e.g. it's a "finite sequence of real numbers".)

Comment: This definition only defines finite sequences, of course.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are hoping to accomplish with your extra cases and verbiage beyond something like: "A symbol that is not a comma is a sequence, and if $S$ is a sequence and $s$ a symbol, then $S,s$ is a sequence."

Comment: @DerekElkins: It is somewhat connected to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2333862/75616): first the language (syntax and inference rules), then the theories built on it.

Comment: @antonio My comment wasn't about your overall goal; it was about your particular definition of sequence. What is inadequate about the definition I gave that warrants the more elaborate and seemingly round-about definition you gave? Your definition seems unnecessarily complicated even given your goal to avoid sets and natural numbers, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @DerekElkins: Sorry, I didn't read properly your previous comment. Once I define a sequence, how can I address the first or last element? If I resort to use the naive metalanguage notion, I could conclude the whole "sequence" word is that of the  metalanguage.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be attempting a recursive definition of finite sequences.  A recursive definition needs 3 things:  construction, distinguishing, and exclusion.

For construction:

> A symbol which is not a comma is a sequence.

It is very very bad style not to distinguish between a singleton and it's element, between $[a]$ and $a$.  This also leaves out the zero length sequence. 
 I suggest simply "$[]$ is a sequence".

> If S is sequence and s a symbol which is not a comma...

I suggest just writing "If [a] is a sequence, then [a,x] is a sequence".

Distinguishability:

You can't just assume that because 2 things are written differently that they are different, for example the sets $\{a, b\} = \{b, a\} = \{a, a, b, b\}$.  So

$$x \ne y \Rightarrow [x] \ne [y]$$
$$[] \ne [a,\dots]$$
$$[a] \ne [b] \Rightarrow [a,x] \ne [b,x]$$

Exclusion

So far you have said what is a set, but you haven't said what isn't a set.  For this induction is the most straightforward, especially since you explicitly don't want to use set theory.

Comment: My point for equivalence. Let $L$ be a language whose variables are strings consisting of a $v$'s followed by one or more strokes `|`. So $v|||$ is a variable in the object language we are describing, but we prefer to _name_ it $v_3$ or $v(3)$ or perhaps $x$. These are metasymbols in the metalanguage describing the object language. Saying explicitly "Let $v_3$ be the name of a variable in $L$" would make it clear that $v_3$ is just one among several possible names for the same/unique string $v|||$, but we tend to say "Let $v_3$ be a variable in $L$". As regards my definition, (cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd) the metasymbol $s$ is a name for some string in the object language. Now, if $\{a,b\}$ and $\{b,a\}$ are strings of the object language, they are different strings so they are different objects. If they are names for objects in the object language, they are outside the scope of the definition. Using the previous example, the string $v||,v|||$ is a sequence in $L$. $S$ or $T$ might be different metasymbols to name that sequence, but "a symbol which is not a comma" does not capture $S$ or $T$ as they are not in $L$.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make it even simpler?

1. Any symbol is a sequence
2. Sequences are closed under concatenation

This is similar to the definition of the [free monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_monoid).

In terms of addressing elements in a sequence: given the sequence $AsB$, the symbol $s$ is the first element if $A$ is trivial, and the last if $B$ is trivial.